# error in applying validation in android application

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-button

I am developing an android application in which iIhave 4 edittext and below a button. I want to apply validation on each field so that any field is not left blank. I have tried a lot of samples and applied same logic, but its not working.

I have coded for that. My java class is
http://pastebin.com/ZdeYZPxX

But problem is that when I enter first edittext and then click button, it works. Can anyone help me to come out of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

See I have made this function in class

```
    public boolean checkForEmpty(String fieldString) {
    if (fieldString.equalsIgnoreCase("")
            || fieldString.equalsIgnoreCase(null))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
    }
```

Then

```
    username = editUserName.getText().toString().trim();
    if (checkForEmpty(username)) {
        Showalert("Please enter User ID");
        editUserName.requestFocus();
    }
```

Comment: if the value is null then fieldString.equalsIgnoreCase("")
            || fieldString.equalsIgnoreCase(null) will through a NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

After showing a `Toast` telling the user that one of the `EditText` is empty you should add a `return` statement to stop the rest of the code(that starts a new `Activity`) being run until the user fills all `EditTexts`:

```
if (un.equals("") || pw.equals("")) {
    if (un.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(BloodPressureScreen.this, "FirstName is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(BloodPressureScreen.this, "LastName is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
}

if (cn.equals("") || em.equals("")) {
    if (cn.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(BloodPressureScreen.this, "Contact is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(BloodPressureScreen.this, "Email is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: this could be done with setting one string in each case as the message, and then on a single line perform `Toast.makeText(...)`

Comment: @bicska88 Of course some improvements could be made to the code above, the snippet I posted was just to solve his issue, nothing else.

Comment: note that you could have saved time with the method suggested by myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean checkForEmpty(String fieldStr) {
    if (fieldStr.length() == 0 )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
    }
```